# Как перевести "количество раз когда знак был присвоен"?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

На [странице знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) есть строка, обозначающая количество награждений знаком.

[Tx:4699](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266659?key=87e8bcb1c1d6264d54bcbe34371c92b5)

> awarded
>
> награждён

Текущий перевод звучит не очень хорошо. Но я не могу придумать вариант, который звучал бы нормально. Все нормальные идеи требуют форм слова в зависимости от числа. И в некоторых случаях перестановки слов:

> присвоен 3 раза
>
> присвоен 5 раз

Давайте придумаем, какой перевод мы там хотим, а потом обратимся к разработчикам чтобы там появились нужные шаблоны в нужном количестве.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Nicolas как мы можем отследить момент, когда новые строки будут добавлены?

Comment: Сложный вопрос. Обычно, бот публикует новые строки в чат, но, конечно же, это могут быть совершенно случайный строки. Здесь проблема в том, что данная строка не имеет множественной формы. Оказалось, что чтобы добавить новые формы для неё необходимо потратить более 10 минут (так как там идет округление). Как результат, я добавил задачку в базу дефектов (обычно, для ошибок перевода, я напрямую в чате просил Семо что–то подправить). А там целый процесс. :( Как только ребята поправят, я отпишусь (и добавлю новый перевод).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ок, спасибо. Было бы просто идеально, если бы бот публиковал в чат также ссылку на тикет и/или приходил и закрывал тикет (т.е. вешал метку "завершено"). :)

Comment: кстати, в оповещениях о награждении сейчас пишется «вы **заработали** знак такой-то за то-то». возможно, неплохо было бы всё это согласовать между собой.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky планам суждено сбыться?

Comment: Я тут проявил произвол, но можно подправить, если что. Правда уже [баг дизайна](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305694/339911) в разработке ;)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Это уже [meta-tag:статус-завершено]. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305581/346987

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Спасибо поправил!

Answer (score 3):

То же самое, только без "уже".

> 1 вручён
>   2 вручено
>   5 вручено

Answer (score 1):

Пробный шар:

> 1 уже вручён
>   2 уже вручено
>   5 уже вручено

Comment: Мне нравится. И без "уже" тоже вариант.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Можно добавить и такой вариант :)

Answer (score 1):

Как было предложено в вопросе:

> присвоен 1 раз
>   присвоено 2 раза
>   присвоено 5 раз

Answer (score 0):

В других строках со знаками у нас используется слово "присвоен":

> 1 присвоен
>   2 присвоено
>   5 присвоено

Answer (score 0):

Так как это число награждений, то может быть так и писать?

> 1 награждение
>   2 награждения
>   5 награждений